# Haskell Map definition Error

Tags: haskell

I'm recent to Haskell and I'm having a problem while trying to write my definition of the map function.
Example: mapi (>2) [1,2,3,4,5] = [False, False, True, True, True]

```
mapi _ [] = 0
mapi f (x:xs) = [f x] ++ mapi f xs
```

When I try this I get the error:

```
No instance for (Num [Bool]) arising from a use of `mapi'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Bool])
In the expression: mapi (> 2) [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]
In an equation for `it': it = mapi (> 2) [1, 2, 3, ....]
```

I know it is related to: mapi _ [] = 0 but I can't find whats the problem, I mean, it has to stop on [] !

Comment: Advice unrelated to your question: don't use `(++)` when `(:)` suffices: `mapi f (x:xs) = f x : mapi f xs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've accidentally returned `0` instead of `[]` in the first case. It should be

```
mapi _ [] = []
mapi f (x:xs) = [f x] ++ mapi f xs
```

If you write a type signature, it helps:

```
mapi :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

so `mapi` is supposed to take a function, a list, and return a list. `0` isn't a list, but `[]` is.

### no instance for....

The error message is saying it was trying to turn `0` into a `[Bool]` which it would do with the `fromInteger` function in the `Num` class, but `[Bool]` isn't a numeric type, so it got stuck. (Every `Num` instance has to have a `fromInteger` function precisely so that integer literals like `0` and `23` can stand for values of that type.)

It suggests you could make an instance for `Num [Bool]` so that it could compile it. That's not a good idea, and this particular error message is often because of a type mismatch rather than a genuine missing instance - worth remembering for next time.

Comment: That's right! I was thinking about boolean, must have confused it. Thank you